# Juice UI: Adding buttons to dialog

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, webforms, juice-ui

I'm trying to add buttons to my dialog using Juice UI but it's not working or I'm doing something wrong.

Following the example in documentation I changed this line

```
<juice:dialog TargetControlID="_Default" AutoOpen="false" runat="server" />
```

for

```
<juice:dialog TargetControlID="_Default" AutoOpen="false" runat="server" Modal="true" Buttons="{'Ok': function() { $(.basic-dialog).dialog('close'); } }" />
```

But the button doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. We've confirmed it's a bug and are tracking it on GitHub here; https://github.com/appendto/juiceui/issues/7

It'll have top priority and be fixed in the upcoming maintenance release.